# What is a high iOS memory usage?

Tags: ios, memory

I tested my app on my device running through Xcode and instruments to monitor CPU and memory levels. My app runs animations on some views and I noticed even after leaving that page the memory levels stayed high and would build on top. At one point the memory levels were around 90MB.

Is this normal?

I have checked that Automatic Referencing Counting is on. Should the memory not clear itself?

Thanks.

This is one of the animations that hold a lot of the memory.

```
-(IBAction)start:(id)sender
{
   animation.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"], nil];
    [animation setAnimationRepeatCount:0];
    animation.animationDuration = 2.5;
    [animation startAnimating];
}
```

[image: Is '# Living' what i need to be worried about?]

This is front he allocations and leaks instrument. Is "# Living" what i need to be worried about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to post code. If memory doesn't clear after leaving a page it means that something is holding on to it. 90MB could be a tad high - are you animating a large, disk-loaded image?

ARC isn't garbage collection - you still have to be careful about what you hold on to

Comment: With Images or animations assuming you need to release the information, how is that done?

I edited the post with the code of the animation.

Comment: and also added a instrument report @davbryn

Comment: Your memory is being tarn up by those png files. They are all loaded at once and because they are owned by the animation object they were all in memory at once. However, ignore Overall Bytes - this is the memory allocated in total (including freed memory), you have 11 MB live bytes and this is fine. You are not using 97MB

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what your application does, 90MB can be a lot. ARC is not magic, and while it greatly helps with memory management, retain cycles can cause memory to build and not be released properly. You should use the allocations and memory leaks instruments to see which objects are not released properly.